# Should I encrypt sharedpreference in android developing?

Tags: android, encryption, oauth-2.0, sharedpreferences

I've developed an application which use OAuth2 with https protocol.
The user's token is saved on SharedPreferences.
I wanna know if saving user's token is critical security problem or not?
and encrypting SharedPreferences is a good solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences of your application can be accessed by other application in your device, therefore shared preference is not a secure place to save sensitive information.

Yes encrypting your token before adding it to the SharedPreferences is always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanna know what method should I used for encrypting shared preferences ? which library do you suggest to be used ?